# Find material noun in a sentence computationally

Tags: nlp

I want to find all [material nouns](https://www.teachingbanyan.com/grammar/material-noun/) in a sentence. Using `pos_tag` set of `nltk` only give `NN, NNS, NNP` etc. Is there any existing work to find out material nouns or how can we solve this problem?

Edit: An example will be

Input: `Don't forget to bring water bottle, a blanket and shoes **during your visit.**`

Output: [`water bottle, blanket, shoes`]

Comment: Welcom to DS Stack Exchange. Please elaborate more in your question, could you add more details?

Comment: A simple approach would be to elaborate a list of materials then check for those nouns. There would be some mistakes (material nouns that have other uses, new materials that don't appears in your list).

Comment: @Leevo added an example of I/O.To  Icrmorin, elaboration is not possible since list is infinite in the universe.

Comment: Does your corpus have a fixed set of materials? Or they could be about anything? It's possible there is not training data for such a task. One option would be to manually label few hundreds of sentences, and train a first classifier on those.

Comment: Alternatively, you could run a PoS tagger on the nltk categories (NN, NNS, NNP), and the work by subtraction, i.e. finding which, among those, do not correspond to material nouns. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: @Leevo, Actually, I didn't want to go building the classifier way. But, seems like there is no other way. Subtraction way is again manual lookup and a common noun can become a material noun and vice-versa (cloth vs cloths vs clothes).

Comment: In subtraction way, you could remove organization, city and people names with NER tagging

Comment: True. let me try out that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your example matches up with the documentation; if I follow the description on the linked website **blanket** and **shoes** don't qualify. If I were to follow your example, I'd say you are looking for *plain* noun phrases.

Comment: How about now when I added `during your visit` where `visit` is NN but I don't want to output it?